# Jenkins with parameterized build

Tags: jenkins

I am configuring a post commit hook and would like to be able to trigger a build on the branch that has been committed.

So far i have set up the `post-commit` hook file

```
curl http://jenkins.local:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=GITHUB_URL/REPO_NAME.git
```

Within Jenkins i have set

```
This build is parameterized

**String Paramenter**
Name: branch

Branches to build: $branch
```

How can i get jenkins to build the branch that has just been committed?

Answer (score 0):

See `http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/api/`:

> **Perform a build**
>
> If the build has parameters, post to [this URL](http://Your_Jenkins/job/Your_job%27s_name/buildWithParameters) [`http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/buildWithParameters`] and provide the parameters as form data.